# Would like to share the HTML as a link

Tags: html, hyperlink, slack

I have a HTML report which I would like to share in the slack as a link so that people could click on the link easily and view the HTML report. I would need to do this programatically. I placed HTML report on the google drive and tried to share the link but unfortunately google drive removes the css part in the report. Please provide any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically share HTML links on Slack you can post message like so:

```
Look at this: <http://www.foo.com|This message *is* a link>
```

For more details check [this page](https://api.slack.com/messaging/composing/formatting#linking-urls).